# Wildcards in javascript manifest

Tags: javascript, asset-pipeline, ace-editor

For my asset manifest I needed to require all the modes of ACE editor in my `application.js` file. This looks like the following:

```
//= require ace/mode-mode1
//= require ace/mode-mode2
//= require ace/mode-mode3
...
```

Is it possible to use a wildcard, to include all modes at once? Something like

```
//= require ace/mode-*
```

Comment: Including all modes at once isn't a good idea, there arr too many of them, and xquery mode is huge.

Comment: makes sense. But aren't they loaded dynamically, when they are needed?

Comment: If the file is not included, 404 is raised behind the scenes - is that a good behaviour?

Comment: Ace loads them dynamically, you need to include ace as a separate script or call `ace.config.set("modePath", ".../path/to/ace/src")` not sure how to do it with asset-pipeline though